# How to read all files in a directory using python

Tags: python

I have a directory with lot of text files. I want to read each text file in the directory and perform some kind of search operation. I take directory name as a command line argument. The error I'm getting is `IsADirectoryError`. Is there anyway we can make this work without any other module?

This is my code:

```
a = sys.argv
files = a[1:-1]

for i in files:
    print(i)
    f = open(i,'rb')
    for line in f:
        try:
            for word in line.split():
            '''Rest of code here'''
```

Comment: you need `os` module for `os.listdir` or `os.walk`

Comment: Martin answer it quite well!
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3207973/4083200) out :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
def read_files_from_dir(dirname):
    for _file in os.listdir(dirname):
        with open(os.path.join(dirname,_file), "r") as fp:
            print fp.read()
```